# Visual Studio Razor formatting with a model that is a collection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a display template in MVC that is for a collection of items, so the first line of my `cshtml` file is as follows:

```
@model IList<Some.Namespace.ViewModels.MyListItem>
```

If I add some new HTML to the file and then do `CTRL + K + D` to auto format, it now changes my model to all lower case like this:

```
@model IList<some.namespace.viewmodels.mylistitem>
```

This is a massive pain to keep changing after auto formatting, because it obviously breaks my html helpers until I correct the casing. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21753187/visual-studio-2013-autoformat-ctrl-k-d-lower-case-issue-with-cshtml) and it said it was due to MVC3.

I'm running VS2013 Update 4 with MVC5 and I still have this problem. I can't find anything in the Text Editor options to change this behaviour.

I'm also using ReSharper 8.2 and Web Essentials 2013 for Update 4.

Is this a known issue or do I have a setting that is breaking things somewhere?

Comment: I'm using VS2013 update 4 and am not able to duplicate the issue.  I installed Web Essentials 2013 for Update 4 and was unable to duplicate the issue.  It may have something to do with Resharper.  I've also noticed that sometimes when copying / pasting code or commenting / uncommenting it changes the cases; I've only noticed that on html elements though.

Comment: Resharper tends to think it knows better ( maybe it does ) If you go to `tools` -> `Options` -> `Environment` -> `KeyBoard` & search for `Edit.MakeLowercase` You should be able to remove the assigned shortcut. Then search for `Edit.FormatSelection` . Or check out this post from jetbrains on [resolving keyboard conflicts](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp80/Resolving_Keyboard_Shortcut_Conflicts.html)

Comment: I'm also having this problem, generic models get lowercased :(

Comment: @MichaelHarper I ended upgrading to VS2015 and Reshaper 9, and now it all works. Not much of a solution though.

Comment: @Alex I noticed 2015 didn't have the issue which is good!

Answer (score 4):

This is what you need to do to fix the formatting issue.

In the `web.config` of **Views folder** overwrite `MvcWebRazorHostFactory` with this line

`<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />`

Close Any open cshtml files and open them.Now formatting the document should work fine, Also I had intellisense problem in razor page which was also resolved. I tried both and did not have any problem.

If you still encounter problems let me know.

Comment: Glad to found this. Thanks! Saves me a hell lot of trouble